# $(...).sideNav is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mdbootstrap

I have just downloaded mdbootstrap. Upon following the instructions for implementing a side-nav on my webpage I get the following error when I try to initialize it:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sideNav is not a function
>       at index.html:133).

Kindly help. I have tried rearranging the order of my files but this doesn't seem to help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

  var sideNavScrollbar = document.querySelector('.custom-scrollbar');
  Ps.initialize(sideNavScrollbar);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watch out, the sideNav component is only for pro users.
Perhaps you try to import a premium component with the "cheap" version of mdbootstrap

[image]

Comment: yeah this is actually it

Answer (score 0):

You need to load jQuery first.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

  var sideNavScrollbar = document.querySelector('.custom-scrollbar');
  Ps.initialize(sideNavScrollbar);  
</script>
```

And make sure you refresh the file in the web browser without cache. You can refresh it by hiting Shitf + F5 in Chrome.

Comment: If the $ object (jquery) is recognized, that means that Jquery is well imported ;-)

Comment: I have tried this but still encounter the same error, i have double checked with your solution and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load jQuery sideNav first. Do like this:

```
$(function(){
  const Ps = new PerfectScrollbar();
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  var sideNavScrollbar = document.querySelector('.custom-scrollbar');
  Ps.initialize(sideNavScrollbar);  
})
```